Firefox: Why is padding-right inside scrolled element missing?
Why is padding-right inside scrolled element missing?


div {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.outer {
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    padding on the right is missing
  </div>
</div>






Actual Result
Expected Result









Also: as workaround I can add display: flex; text-wrap: nowrap; on .outer.

It's not missing. See the updated runnable snippet of your own code.

@RokoC.Buljan it is missing (I'm on Firefox)
